# Error During import user from AD to my custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to get user from active directory in my webpart but i am sruck somewhere
please help me my code is as below.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;

namespace LdapTest2008
{
    [Guid("028042d8-7f77-4674-8b19-61b282e5ddf8")]
    public class LdapTest2008 : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        public LdapTest2008()
        {
        }


        Label lblUsers = new Label();

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            // TODO: add custom rendering code here.
            // Label label = new Label();
            // label.Text = "Hello World";
            // this.Controls.Add(label);
        }

        public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.RenderControl(writer);
            StringCollection StrCollectionReturn = new StringCollection();
            string strGroup = "My Group";
           
           StrCollectionReturn= GetGroupMembers(strGroup);

           lblUsers.Text = StrCollectionReturn.ToString();
           this.Controls.Add(lblUsers);
           writer.Write(lblUsers.Text);
       
        }


        //Query Active Directory to get users from Active Directory Groups
            public StringCollection GetGroupMembers(string strGroup)

            {
                string domain = "LDAP://Domain.COM";
                
                string domainAndUsername = "Domain.COM\\username";
                string passWord = "password";
                StringCollection groupMemebers = new StringCollection(); 
                

            try

            {
                            DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(domain,domainAndUsername,passWord);

                            DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher("(CN=" + strGroup + ")");
                            srch.SizeLimit = 0;
                            srch.PageSize = 1000;

                            SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();

                            foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
                            {
                                ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = default(ResultPropertyCollection);
                                resultPropColl = rs.Properties;


                                foreach (Object memberColl in resultPropColl["member"])
                                {
                                    DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+ memberColl);

                                    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userProps = gpMemberEntry.Properties;

                                    //getting user properties from AD

                                    object obVal = userProps["displayName"].Value;

                                    object obAcc = userProps["sAMAccountName"].Value;

                                    if (null != obVal)
                                    {

                                        groupMemebers.Add("User Name:" + obAcc.ToString() + ", User login name:" + obVal.ToString() + "<br>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
               }
            

                        catch (Exception ex)

                        {
                            ex.GetBaseException();
                           // writer.Write(ex.Message);
                        }

                       
                           
                  return groupMemebers;
                
            }
    }

}
```

When debug this code I'm stuck here:

```
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher("(CN=" + strGroup + ")");
```

It give mes error found null value.

What I am doing wrong?

#### Update:

I have made one silly mistake i forgot to pass Directory Entry object to searcher.

```
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(ent, "(CN=" + strGroup + ")"); ,
```

Now it's work but now i got error in

```
DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+ memberColl);
```

I have also tried by passing domain name also

```
DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DomainName"+ memberColl);
```

But still it give me error "threw an exception of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe strGroup is empty? Debug and see what it contains.

Also might wanna test that same string in a LDAPtool to see if it brings out any results like that, if strGroup isn't empty.

---

Well I think you're using the classes the wrong way. And you're LDAP string might be wrong too.

Here's an example of a the DirectorySearcher-class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180885(VS.80).aspx

Here's another with the same Exception you were getting:
http://forums.asp.net/p/322041/322460.aspx